# Windows media server doesn't stop after playing 1 file from list

Tags: xml, windows-media-player, windows-media-server, asx

I'm playing Windows Media audio, triggered by an ASX meta-file which looks like this:

```
<asx version="3.0" BannerBar="none">
  <title>Foo</title>
  <author>Bar</author>
  <copyright>Baz</copyright>
  <moreinfo href="http://company.com/"/>
  <entry>
    <title>Audio Stream</title>
    <ref href="mms://media1.company.com/bof.asf"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Audio Stream</title>
    <ref href="mms://media2.company.com/bof.asf"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Apology</title>
    <ref href="http://www.company.com/apology.asf"/>
  </entry>
</asx>
```

as you can probably tell, it's supposed to *try* to play the file on media1.company.com if it can, then try the file on media2.company.com if the first one fails, then play the apology if both fail.

What *actually* happens is, you hear all three. The failover process seems to, well, fail, and the server doesn't know the first file has successfully played.

What can be done to fix this? Is it a server setting? Is something wrong with the XML format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of "I don't think this means what you think it means"

Basically you created a playlist and told media player to play all of those files.

Instead try something like this:

```
<entry>
<title>Audio Stream</title>
<ref href="mms://blah">
<ref href="mms://blahsecondattempt">
<ref href="mms://blahthird">
</entry>
```

More information is at [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: Thank you! As you can probably tell I'm having something of a slap-forehead moment.